# MS Access: setting table column Caption or Description in DDL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ddl

Is it possible to set a table column's Caption or Description properties in MS Access using DDL? Ideally, we could include them in a CREATE TABLE statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use DAO to set *Caption* and *Description* properties as [Andrea suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3521333/77335).  Just be aware that both those properties are user-defined, not default properties ... meaning that they don't exist before you assign them a value.

For example the following statement triggers error 3270, *'Property not found'*, because I have not assigned a *Description* for the `id` field:

```vb
Debug.Print CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblFoo").Fields("id").Properties("Description")
```

In order to assign a *Description* value for the field, I would first have to `CreateProperty` for *Description* then `Append` the new property to the field's *Properties* collection.  Rather than write code to show you, I will suggest you use Allen Browne's [SetPropertyDAO](http://allenbrowne.com/AppPrintMgtCode.html#SetPropertyDAO) function.  That function will handle the details for you.  Be sure to grab the `HasProperty` function, too, because it is called by `SetPropertyDAO`.  (The code for `HasProperty` is on the same web page, immediately below the `SetPropertyDAO` function code.)

Comment: Thank! Appreciate the confirmation -- and the extra info in how the properties work.

Answer (score 1):

Alas, it's not possibile to change or set some properties of a table or field  by Access DDL. We had a similar problem, involving also relations between tables, and we resorted to DAO.
It' quite simple anyway, you'll be using objects such as `DAO.Database`, `DAO.TableDef` and `DAO.Field`.

Comment: "Resorted to DAO?" WTF? I'd say "resorting to DDL" would be the real step down, as DAO is by far the best way to interact fully with Jet/ACE databases. DDL is what you use when you *can't* use DAO.

Comment: Hi David, I'd agree with you if all the database panorama was Access. We tend  to use DDL since it's much more generic: write once, run (almost) everywere (almost) unmodified :)

Comment: But these properties are not generic SQL field properties, but specific to MS Access. Secondly, these properties have no meaning except within Access, so attempting to write generic DDL for that context doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: I agree that DAO is much more flexible, but in this case DDL was much easier. We were migrating table definitions from a distributed MySQL database to a local Access db and we wanted to put the MySql "comment" properties in the Description or Caption. Easiest to just dump the SQL, run some regex and then import it back to Access as DDL. Thanks for all the feedback!

Comment: I think the goal of cross-platform SQL is impossible when you're using properties specific to one database or another.