# Creating a table using SQL In Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I am trying to create this table in access SQl. I know the basics of creating tables. However I am stuck with extra details to each field. HEre is what I need to create:

[image]

How would i go about setting required to yes/no, the caption and primary key etc..?

Comment: Doesn't MS Access have a manual that explains the SQL statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Setting Yes/No**

Setting yes/no is done by adding a `NOT NULL` constraint to the field definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IceCream (
    Flavor TEXT(25) NOT NULL
);
```

---

**Setting Caption**

There doesn't seem to be a way to set this using SQL. See [MS Access: setting table column Caption or Description in DDL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521188/ms-access-setting-table-column-caption-or-description-in-ddl).

---

**Primary Key**

The primary key can be set using the `PRIMARY KEY` clause on a single field, or as a separate `CONSTRAINT` definition. If you have a multi-field primary key, you must use the second form.

```
CREATE TABLE IceCream (
    Flavor TEXT(25) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE Sundae (
    Name   TEXT(25),
    Flavor TEXT(25),
    CONSTRAINT PK_Sundae
        PRIMARY KEY (Name)
);
```

---

**Foreign Key**

The foreign key can be set with a `CONSTRAINT` definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IceCream (
    Flavor TEXT(25) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE Sundae (
    Name   TEXT(25) PRIMARY KEY,
    Flavor TEXT(25),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Sundae_IceCream
        FOREIGN KEY (Flavor)
        REFERENCES IceCream (Flavor)
);
```

---

*Disclaimer*: These are not examples of proper database design (normalization and such). They're just examples I made up on the spot.

---

**References**

- [CREATE TABLE Statement (Microsoft Access SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837200%28v=office.15%29.aspx)
- [CONSTRAINT Clause (Microsoft Access SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836971%28v=office.15%29.aspx)