# How to Access Metadata Fields of an MS Access Database Programmatically?

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, database-metadata, metadata-extractor

I'm working with a Microsoft Access database stored in a `.ACCDB` file.  I’m interested in retrieving metadata on various table fields.  Using the Microsoft Access GUI, I can view this data in the "Design View" interface of a table. The specific fields I’m interested in include "Required", "Allow Zero Length", and "Indexed".

[Design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTk6i.png)

[Properties Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfBaE.png)

Question: Is there a way to read these metadata fields without using the MS-Access GUI?  Preferably, with a SQL query or a Python script, but any programatic way to access this metadata would be acceptable.  Even something as simple as a command line utility that could dump the information in a my `.ACCDB` file to a console would work for my needs.

Any references or Google terms that would point me in the right direction would be helful.

I expect there is some programmatic way to retrieve this metadata from a .ACCDB file, but I don't know what to search for.

Comment: Hidden system tables have info and these tables can be queried. And yes, code can loop through object collections and output their properties. Will probably find most code samples are for VBA. Your question is too broad and lacks code for analysis and is therefore not suitable for SO. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75353838/ms-access-table-and-tabledef-properties